# Is this dubious use of a non-prototype function declaration valid?

Tags: c, prototype, standards, language-lawyer

Is this valid C (C99) code?

```
int f();
int g(int x)
{
    if (x<0) return f(x);
    else return f(x,x);
}
```

Obviously the program has undefined behavior if `g` is ever called with a negative argument and `f` is not a function that takes a single `int` argument, or if `g` is ever called with a non-negative argument and `f` is not a function that takes two `int` arguments. But otherwise?

Consider as an example this separate source file which calls `g` from the above and provides `f`:

```
int g();
#ifdef FOO
int f(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int main() { return g(1); }
#else
int f(int a) { return a; }
int main() { return g(-1); }
#endif
```

Comment: That won't even compile, surely?  Let alone link.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: Have you tried? It compiles and links for me. (Without errors or warnings with `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`)

Comment: @Oli: Are you confusing C and C++ perhaps? There is certainly no real-world linker that remotely cares about a C function's signature at link time. And if the usage in my question is valid, which I suspect it is, then that's proof that a linker is not allowed to care about the signature.

Comment: @R.. - Keep in mind that linkers often take input from multiple languages - not just C. x86 Assembly code might be mixed, which could mean the linker wouldn't know what arguments the function takes.

Comment: @Charles: No, I hadn't tried it... My knowledge of C is clearly lacking, then!  Why is one allowed to declare a function, and then call it using a different set of arguments?

Comment: I'm aware that linkers can take input from multiple languages, but that does not free them from the requirement to correctly link programs in any given one of the languages they support. If this is valid C code, a linker that fails to link is is broken.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: You have to call a function with arguments that are compatible with the parameters that it is defined with. You don't have to have a prototype for the function in scope when you call it (with some exceptions). Note that `int f();` is a declaration of a function but not a prototype.

Comment: @Oli: In this case, the declaration does not specify the arguments. It's an old non-prototype declaration form of dubious/limited value, and in this question I'm exploring one potential (ab)use of it. :-)

Comment: @Charles, @R: So are you implying that if you had declared `f` as, say, `int f(void);`, this *would* be a prototype, and the compiler would therefore complain?

Comment: @Charles: Well, then I've learnt something new today!  (that `int f();` *is* valid, and distinct from `int f(void);`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's ask the other way around: *Why would it **not** be valid?*. I really can't find any argument or rule that forbids the above code. The function call in the respective other branch is never executed (although discussion in the comments indicate it's not so easy!).

Comment: Depending on the argument `array[n]` might be valid even if `n` had a negative value. It would be a more compelling example if `array` where an array and not a `pointer`.

Comment: Well what if I declared `int f(), h();` and performed `if (x<0) return f(x); else return h(x);` and ensured that `x` was always negative, but never defined `h`? I would expect a link-time error unless the compiler happened to optimize out the case where `x` is non-negative. This is a little bit different from my question, but I'm trying to track down exactly what the difference is.

Comment: By the way, I agree with your reasoning, and I think if it's correct, it implies that the implementation **cannot** do any C++-like symbol name mangling or other tricks based on the signature of a function.

Comment: I liked your old example code better. In your new example (1) it's unclear what you mean by omit the return, (2) running off the end of a function is not undefined behavior, unless the return value gets used by the caller, and (3) your new function has serious UB (integer overflow) on all but the tiniest arguments. :-)

Comment: @R.. i replaced it because the `array[n]` example relied on runtime data (the value of `n`). However, the new example doesn't rely on runtime data: There is no return statement, but the function is value-returning and we use its return value (`n + fac(n-1)`). Just like in our case, the source code contains both a `f(x, x)` and `f(x)` - no function definition ever could accept both of those set of arguments (ellipsis functions are not allowed to be declared by `void f();` prior to the call). Quite probably there are better examples though :) I will remove my example since I think it's poor

Comment: @R.. that's because the Standard requires the program to provide a definition if its identifier is used in an expression. It doesn't require the program to provide a definition only if the function is called. I think the case is different for f(x) vs f(x, y) (the wording is at 6.5.2.2/6 of TC3). The expression needs to be evaluated for that wording to take effect, I think. But carefully reading, I can't find a clear indicator of this, really. Maybe this would be a good usenet question for comp.lang.c or something?

Comment: @R.. yes that seems to disallow implementations to mangle the call based on number of arguments. I wasn't really aware that that follows from this, but it indeed seems so. Well spotted.

Comment: @Johannes: cf 6.5.3.2/4, maybe? "If an invalid value has been assigned to the pointer, the behavior of the unary * operator is undefined". Clearly this means *if the expression is evaluated*. There's nothing wrong with `char *x = 0; if (x != 0) *x;`, even though an invalid value has been assigned to `x`, and the expression `*x` has undefined behavior in that case. I agree with you that it would be nice to find definitive text to that effect, though, that behavior "semantics" in the expressions chapter refer to the effect of evaluating the expression, not the effect of the expression existing.

Comment: @Steve yeah I think you are right. Good point comparing to 6.5.3.2 :)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. Some of the others are nice too, but yours was the first and if I count your followup comments along with the answer, it's definitely the best.

Answer (score 3):

C99 (6.5.2.2 Function calls, item 8) says the number and types of parameters and arguments "are not compared" if the function definition does not have a prototype.

I have seen this (ab)used in the wild with function pointers. An array of `void (*)()` contained both `void (*)(struct Client *)` and `void (*)(struct Client *, int parc, char *parv[])` function pointers. Based on the array index, the code passed the extra parameters or not.

In this case, the compiler has no (reasonable) way to check the number of parameters in advance, even if it has all relevant code.

I think this is dirty code and I fixed that particular instance.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree that it is valid so long as the incorrect function call is never evaluated by the C abstract machine.

There is another, simpler, way to come to your conclusion about the linker, though: Since this is allowed:

```
int f();
int (*fp)() = f;
```

The linker must be able to find the address of `f()` without knowing its actual definition.  Its symbol must therefore be able to be determined without knowing the actual definition.

Comment: It occurs to me that this is likely why C++ changed the meaning of `int f();` - it had to, to allow function overloading.

Answer (score 0):

What if it's `f(int x, ...)` and it looks at the sign of its first argument to know how many (0 or 1) varargs it got?

Comment: Then it's undefined behaviour because the function is declared with `, ...` and called without a prototype.

Comment: What Charles said. Variadic functions **absolutely require** a prototype.

Comment: Perhaps more excitingly, what if it's `f()`, and the sign of the first argument tells it how many parameters it has, and the function is actually implemented in assembler, not C, with knowledge of the C calling convention so that it can read the correct arguments without using varargs? If this code isn't valid, you can't do that, but as R. says in comments above, no linker in practice would go out of its way to prevent it.

Comment: @Steve: At the point of writing and linking asm, you're already outside the scope of C and in the scope of a particular implementation, which almost surely allows the code I've written. I was more interested in it from a standards perspective and what requirements this places on the implementation (for example, a requirement not to mangle function names based on argument types).

Comment: @R.: fair enough, I just thought it was another reason why one might want the standard to permit it, in the spirit of Ben's suggestion.

Comment: @R: A number of platforms mangle linker function names based on signature in at least some situations.  The Keil 8x51 compiler, for example, adds an underscore to the names of functions that have arguments passed in registers, but does not add one to functions that do not pass arguments in registers.  It would be possible for a library to include two versions of functions with arguments--one accepting arguments in memory and another in registers--and link with callers using either convention.  Functions without arguments would not need duplicate definitions.

Comment: @R: Also, HiTech's compiler for the PIC supplies function signature information to the linker.  This is used both to provide warnings, and also to allow the linker to build a call tree if a program uses function pointers (any function pointer of a given signature is assumed to be capable of calling any function with that signature).  To be sure, neither the Keil nor HiTech compilers are perfectly ANSI compliant, but the linkers do "go out of their way" to provide at least some signature checking.  BTW, many PC C compilers mangle names based upon calling convention, though I believe...

Comment: @R: ...they handle the "with arguments" and "no arguments" cases identically.

Answer (score 0):

It is valid(well, it might depend on which standard you are using). You should read something about [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl).

Basically, if `f` takes one or no arguments, I'd expect no problems.
If `f` takes two or more arguments, those other arguments(other than the first) can be expected to have junk(apparently random) values.

Consider this piece of code:

```
int f(int x, int y);
int g(int x)
{
   int k; //No value
   if (x<0) return f(x, k);
   else return f(x, x);
}
```

Of course, it is a bad idea. You should prefer to explicitly declare all arguments.

You may also use `int f(void);` to explicitly declare that f takes no arguments.

Be aware that C++'s function overloading might cause problems, but I assume this isn't a concern since you tagged your question with `c`.
Also, some calling conventions might cause significant problems.

Comment: `int f(...);` is completely invalid. There is no way to write a function in standard C which has a lone `...` as its arguments, and prototyping a non-variadic function as if it were variadic, or vice versa, or failing to prototype a variadic function at all, all result in undefined behavior.

Comment: It is always undefined behaviour if the number of arguments don't match the number of parameters in a function call. The question is whether it is valid to have such an expression in a program if it isn't actually evaluated.

Comment: Thank you Charles. I'd give that comment +10 if I could because you've expressed my question better in one sentence than I did in the whole original question.

Comment: @R.. Hmm. You are correct. I thought I read it somewhere long ago, but I also found a source stating it is invalid. I'll delete that part.