# Functions of varying arity called through pointers to functions of unspecified arguments

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm 99% convinced that this is legitimate after reviewing the C standard and several comp.lang.c posts, but am hoping that someone can provide the precise language in the standard that allows (or forbids) this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double id (double x) { return x; }
double add2 (double x, double y) { return x + y; }
double add3 (double x, double y, double z) { return x + y + z; }

typedef double (*fp) ();
static fp funcs[] = { id, add2, add3 };

int main (void)
{
    printf("id(5.3) = %f\n", funcs[0](5.3));
    printf("add2(5.3, 6.1) = %f\n", funcs[1](5.3, 6.1));
    printf("add3(5.3, 6.1, 7.2) = %f\n", funcs[2](5.3, 6.1, 7.2));

    return 0;
}
```

The provided example gave the expected results for me under MinGW gcc 4.4.0 using `-Wall -pedantic -ansi`.

Considerations:

- I'm aware that calls to functions with unspecified parameters implicitly promote integral arguments according to the integral promotion rules and `float` arguments to `double`. Does this behavior change in any way when calling through a function pointer to a function of unspecified parameters? (I don't see why it would.)
- I came across several posts implying that calls to functions with `...` specifiers (e.g. `double uhoh (double x, ...)`) are not permitted through function pointers to functions of unspecified parameters. This makes sense from an implementation perspective, but I haven't been able to pin down the clause in the standard which forbids this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I can suggest that the standard function call syntax:

```
void foo(int);
foo(3);
```

is defined in terms of `foo` decaying to a function pointer, then being invoked; therefore I don't see why there would be any difference between your situation and a "standard" function call.

Second, n1256 6.5.2.2 details function call semantics, and it seems pretty well-defined for a function pointer with no prototype provided the number and type of arguments matches the number and type of parameters.

An empty parameter list is incompatible with a variadic parameter list according to n1256 6.7.5.3p15:

> If one type has a parameter type list
>   and the other type is specified by a
>   function declarator that is not part
>   of a function definition and that
>   contains an empty identifier list, the
>   parameter list shall not have an
>   ellipsis terminator and the type of
>   each parameter shall be compatible
>   with the type that results from the
>   application of the default argument
>   promotions.

This means it is a constraint violation (6.5.16.1p1) to assign a variadic function pointer to a pointer-to-function with no prototype, since you are assigning pointers to incompatible types.

I would guess that casting a variadic function pointer to a non-prototyped function pointer is also UB and possibly a CV; but I haven't checked.

Comment: Is it the cast or the calling (through a cast pointer) that has undefined behavior in your last paragraph? I was under the impression that the cast is valid as long as you cast back to the right variadic type before making a call using the pointer.

Comment: @R.. i don't know, it's a guess. That's what "presumably" was supposed to communicate. There's only so much standardese I want to read in one go :) I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Good point re: "standard" function calls being defined in terms of decay to a function pointer. I remember reading that but didn't make the connection at the time! 6.7.5.3 is exactly what I was looking for too. Thanks!

Comment: My understanding of the standard is the same as @R.'s - you can cast function pointers (including to variadic functions) to other function pointer types, and it's well-defined as long as you cast it back to the correct type before calling it.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this program has entirely well-defined behavior as long as the arguments *when you make the call* are of the number and types matching those in the definition of the function that gets called. See 6.5.2.2 paragraph 6. My related question may also be of interest:

[Is this dubious use of a non-prototype function declaration valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179366/is-this-dubious-use-of-a-non-prototype-function-declaration-valid)

Answer (score 0):

The code is well-defined as long as all parameter types promote to themselves and all supplied argument are of correct type.

If you want to get back some measure of type-safety, you could use explicit casts or unions, eg

```
#include <stdio.h>

static double id(double x) { return x; }
static double add2(double x, double y) { return x + y; }
static double add3(double x, double y, double z) { return x + y + z; }

union func
{
    double (*as_unary)(double x);
    double (*as_binary)(double x, double y);
    double (*as_ternary)(double x, double y, double z);
};

static const union func funcs[] = {
    { .as_unary = id },
    { .as_binary = add2 },
    { .as_ternary = add3 }
};

int main(void)
{
    printf("id(5.3) = %f\n", funcs[0].as_unary(5.3));
    printf("add2(5.3, 6.1) = %f\n", funcs[1].as_binary(5.3, 6.1));
    printf("add3(5.3, 6.1, 7.2) = %f\n", funcs[2].as_ternary(5.3, 6.1, 7.2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i suppose the union provides type safety in that it will police your argument types better; but it won't stop you using the wrong prototype if you forget. Given you have to remember the correct prototype either way, i'm not sure this is much of a win.

Comment: @Philip: in my opinion, it is definitely a win because you avoid argument promotion (which can introduce subtle bugs) and restrict possible signatures to a known set